# Why is the global variable taking precedence over the project variables?

Tags: gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci.yml, gitlab-ci-trigger

I am trying to understand why my pipeline ends up using the global variable value instead of the one I defined at the project level.  My understanding was that project variables take precedence over global ones.

.gitlab-ci.yml

```
variables:
  REGION: '"null"' # this value ends up being used

include:
  - local: header.yml

stages:
  - validate

Create Test:
  stage: validate
  variables:
    SUBDOMAIN: e2e-sn-$CI_PIPELINE_ID
  trigger:
    include: integration_test.yml
    strategy: depend
    forward:
      pipeline_variables: true
  rules:
    - if: $RUN_E2E_INTEGRATION_TESTS == "true"
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"
      variables:
        RESTART_TEST: 'true'
      when: manual
      changes:
        - 'venom/e2e/**/*'
```

header.yml

```
.e2e:
  rules:
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "parent_pipeline"

.venomE2E:
  variables: 
    VENOM_VAR_region: $REGION
    VENOM_VAR_subdomain: $SUBDOMAIN
  extends:
    - .e2e
```

integration_test.yml

```
include:
  - local: header.yml

stages:
  - Create

Create site:
  stage: Create
  extends: .venomE2E
  script:
    - venom run e2e/create.yaml
```

I have 'REGION' defined as a project variable so I was expecting "VENOM_VAR_region" to contain it's value.  However, it instead has the global variable's value

Comment: Does the same behavior happen if you set `forward:yaml_variables:false` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it is written in the [docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/#cicd-variable-precedence), `trigger variables` have the highest precedence.

In your example you are using `trigger.forward.pipeline_variables: true` setting, which makes `REGION` a trigger variable and therefore its precedence becomes the highest. This behavior is also described in the [docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/downstream_pipelines.html#control-what-type-of-variables-to-forward-to-downstream-pipelines).